# The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Node

Tags: java, xml, oracle11g

I try to read an XMLDocument. Therefore I user the oracle XMLParser.

the methode getTextContent() is giving me problems. I have no problem retrieving the nodeName. But I can't retrieve the value. I tried getNodeValue, but that returns null.

This is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
        <test>
            <name>first</name>
        </test>
    </root>
```

My code

```
import oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument;

public class XMLReader {

    public static void checkRules(XMLDocument doc) {

        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("test").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName());;
        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("test").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
    }
}
```

and console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Node
```

Comment: Maybe some classpaths are mixed up. Are you sure you are only using a single lib for XML stuff? Is there some wrong import? I am using these: "import org.w3c.dom.Node;" from w3c and it works fine. Here an older class I created at the beginning of this year: https://pastebin.com/R93uzDbk it uses xml files to store level information. Maybe it helps you if you take a look. Good Luck!

Comment: @Joeri Venekamp, In `rules.getElementsByTagName()`, What is `rules`?

Comment: I made a typo, made the code more generic. Fixed the typo.

Comment: I have to use the XMLParser ffrom oracle. For the apliction must run within a oracle SOA suite